# Session disappear while working on ajax in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, session

Hi all currently am working in chat functionality in my project.

When a user start his conversation an id will be saved in the session, the id will same  throughout the chat id value stored in session gets disappear

In the following code i have mentioned the issues

Initially there is no session value for id then it will enter into to the if condition and session value will be created for id during next loop it should not allow to the if condition but in my case its allowing its because the session value get disappear

```
extract($this->input->post());
  $loc=get_location($this->session->userdata('ip_address'));
  $this->session->set_userdata('chatusername',$username);
  $this->session->set_userdata('chatemail',$email);

   if($this->session->userdata('id')=='')
      {

         $messageid= sprintf("%06d", mt_rand(100000, 999999));
         $this->session->set_userdata('id',$messageid);

      }
    $data['message_id']=$this->session->userdata('id');
    $data['username']=$username;
    $data['email']=$email;
    $data['department_id']=$department_id; 
    $data['message']=$message;
    $this->db->insert('message',$data);
```

help me to solve this issue am confused can't find the cause of the issue

Comment: are you saving session in db ? Go to your config.php under application folder and set use session database option to true.
Also check your user_agent option. If database option and user_agent option are true then make user_agent false and try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this solution and mentioned comments in the same: http://blog.jonaszamora.es/en/codeigniter-fix-for-session-loss-caused-by-ajax/